# How to dynamically update range slider

Tags: javascript, html

I've created the following code to show the user their range slider value.  However, it only shows the value when the user stops moving the slider.  Is there a way to show the value WHILE the user drags the range slider?  I'm looking for a way to do this in vanilla JS.

```js
function updateInput(val) {
      document.getElementById('textInput').innerHTML=val; 
    }
```

```html
<input type="range" name="rangeInput" min="0" max="100" onchange="updateInput(this.value);">                                                       
    <p id="textInput"></p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
<input type="range" name="rangeInput" min="0" max="100" onchange="updateInput(this.value);" oninput="updateInput(this.value)" >                                                       
    <p id="textInput"></p>
```

`oninput` is not supported in IE10, so you have to use both, `oninput` and `onchange`.

Here is the **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e3gdtp4L/)**

Comment: Thanks for watching compatibilty!

Answer (score 1):

Use `oninput` instead of `onchange`.

[Magical proof!](http://jsfiddle.net/b3ytbbud/)

Answer (score 1):

onmousemove function make this happen:

```
<input type="range" name="rangeInput" min="0" max="100" onmousemove="document.getElementById('textInput').innerHTML=this.value;">                                                       
    <p id="textInput"></p>
```